# Need some help fixing a For Each loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason this loop doesn't call the sub formatCells to run on each cell in the selection. It will only run on the top left cell in the selected range.

```
Sub selectionLoop()

    Dim rng As Range, itm As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    For Each itm In rng
        Call formatCells
    Next

End Sub

Sub formatCells() 'Formats cells based on what is in the cell

    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(ActiveCell) = True Then 'Searching for text in the cell

        With ActiveCell.Font  'Applies text format
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 18
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        .Bold = True
        End With

        With ActiveCell
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        End With
    Else
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "#,##0_);(#,##0)"  'Applies number format
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Pass `FormatCells` a `Range` variable; don't use `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Or just move your loop into `FormatCells`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some improvements to your code:

1. Use [option explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) to avoid trouble with undeclared variables
2. Name your variables to [something meaningful](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/21759/A-Guide-to-Writing-Understandable-and-Maintainable-VBA-Code.html)
3. Don't [rely on ActiveCell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/1521579) unless you really mean it
4. [Optional](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=124:conditional-statements-in-excel-vba-selectcase-statement-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475): replace your `IF` with `Select Case`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub selectionLoop()

    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set targetRange = Selection

    ' Loop through each cell in range
    For Each cell In targetRange
        ' Pass the cell to procedure
        formatCells cell
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub formatCells(ByVal cell As Range) 'Formats cells based on what is in the cell

    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(cell.Value) = True Then 'Searching for text in the cell

        With cell.Font  'Applies text format
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 18
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        .Bold = True
        End With

        With cell
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        End With
    Else
        cell.NumberFormat = "#,##0_);(#,##0)"  'Applies number format
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you, and the links are very helpful as well.

Comment: Awesome, please consider marking the answer so others may find it too